# pI'm trying to What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python, list, function

pI'm
[2, 4, 2300, 4],[3, 6, 7500, 3],[2, 4, 4100, 7],[2, 4, 2800, 5],[2, 4, 5800, 2], [2, 4, 4800, 8], [2, 4, 2750, 4]]
cars = [[2, 4, 2300, 4],[3, 6, 7500, 3],[2, 4, 4100, 7],[2, 4, 2800, 5],[2, 4, 5800, 2], [2, 4, 4800, 8], [2, 4, 2750, 4]]

Comment: define `list1=[]` in your function and unindent the `return` function to the same level as `for i in range (a,c)`

Comment: You should add `list1` to your function and it should have the same indentation level as your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your return statement is wrongly indented, and therefore ends the function too quickly:

```
def divisor(a, c):
    list = []
    for i in range(a, c):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 7 == 0:
            list.append(i)
    return list


b = 1234
d = 1422
chamador = divisor(b, d)
print(chamador)
```

#### Output:

```
[1236, 1239, 1242, 1245, 1246, 1248, 1251, 1253, 1254, 1257, 1260, 1263, 1266, 1267, 1269, 1272, 1274, 1275, 1278, 1281, 1284, 1287, 1288, 1290, 1293, 1295, 1296, 1299, 1302, 1305, 1308, 1309, 1311, 1314, 1316, 1317, 1320, 1323, 1326, 1329, 1330, 1332, 1335, 1337, 1338, 1341, 1344, 1347, 1350, 1351, 1353, 1356, 1358, 1359, 1362, 1365, 1368, 1371, 1372, 1374, 1377, 1379, 1380, 1383, 1386, 1389, 1392, 1393, 1395, 1398, 1400, 1401, 1404, 1407, 1410, 1413, 1414, 1416, 1419, 1421]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using a simple list comprehension:

```
a = 1234
b = 1422
>>> [i for i in range(a, b) if not i % 3 or not i % 7]
[1236,
 1239,
 1242,
 1245,
...]
```